# Recaptcha v2 implementation with PHP

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

Consider the following form:

```
<form action="https://bookings.com/book?venue_id=5e421312312" method="POST" role="form">
            
  <input name="enquiry_type" type="hidden" value="enquiry"/>
  <input name="source" type="hidden" value="partner"/>
  <input name="venue_group" type="hidden" value="5e421312312"/>               
  <input name="return_url" type="hidden" value="https://www.returnurl.co.uk/enquiry-received" />

  <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>  
  <input id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="" type="text" value="" required/>

  <button type="submit">
  ENQUIRE
  </button>

</form>
```

So it has an action already and some hidden values that get passed.

What I wish to do is add Google Recaptch v2 to this and check the response using PHP. I think I can figure that out, by changing the action to another php file to process, but when it comes to this part below how do I submit the form with the current action and hidden fields as displayed above and of course all of the fields?

```
    if($responseKeys["success"]) {
            //WHAT TO DO HERE ?
    } else {
            echo 'Recaptcha error';
    }
```

Comment: within the success block, send a POST request using cURL (or other), what is the issue here? Genrally, you don't add reCaptcha to a 3rd party form!!

Comment: Its a third party form but a customised one. The problem is it is getting spammed! Can you show me an example of what you have mentioned above? Basically I just need to submit the form once the recaptcha check is successful

Comment: For your case, you should add some security check(s) otherwise user can bypass the reCAPTCHA and submit directly to `https://bookings.com/book?venue_id=xxxxxxxx` even thru a robot. The simplest way is to set a session variable by calling a PHP script when $responseKeys["success"] is true., so that the next page (on submission) will check this session variable to verify the reCaptcha is successful (or course cURL is also an option as stated by Omishah above)

Comment: Thanks @KenLee, any examples of how I do this?